# how to summing text field in same id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input fields like this

```
<input id="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly />
<input id="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly/>
<input id="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly/>
<input id="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly/>
<input id="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly/>
```

how to summing text field in same id in javascript?

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#total").val(nilai);
<script>
```

Comment: your title is your problem

Comment: `id`s need to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

```
var total = 0
$('input[name="nilai"]').each(function(){
   total+=parseInt($(this).val())
})
console.log(total)
```

Comment: You should also recommend the duplicate IDs be removed as they are invalid.

Comment: Not to mention, **always** supply the radix to `parseInt`: `parseInt($(this).val(), 10)`.

Comment: @André Dion: Or use `~~` for faster/shorter base 10 integer conversion :)

Answer (score 1):

**Do not** use duplicate IDs; they result in HTML that's not valid. Use a class instead. And don't use duplicate names unless it is absolutely necessary.

```
var sum = 0;
$('.nilai').each(function() {
     sum += +this.value;
});
alert( sum ); //Result '50'
```

```js
var sum = 0;
$('.nilai').each(function() {
  sum += +this.value;
});
alert( sum );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly />
<input class="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly/>
<input class="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly/>
<input class="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly/>
<input class="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, same ids should not be present. So replace them with `class`

```
<input class="nilai" name="nilai" type="text" value="10" readonly />
// (...) more elements
```

Then you can do

```
var str = $('.nilai').map(function(){
   return +$(this).val();
}).get().reduce(function(p, c){ return p + c;  })

$('#total').val(str);
```

If you do not want to use my suggestion, then just change the selector to `[name=nilai]` which is attribute selector.

Comment: I am curious: How does a join allow you to *add* up the numbers? :)

Comment: sorry. Thought had to concatenate the string. Didn't see that the value was a number. Though now, since Aakil has answered the obvious, my solution is an overkill..

Comment: You fixed the issue I pointed out with the `join` call, but introduced another with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). `Array.prototype.reduce` isn't available in < IE9

Comment: @AndréDion I know it is an overkill, will delete post :)

Comment: @BayuSanjaya Thanks, but well, I suppose not :) It's an overkill so I'd advise you to use Aakil's answer ;)

Comment: @Bayu Sanjaya: Beware of over-complicating solutions (no matter how much genius appears involved). `Aakil Fernandes` solution is more readable. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie you could've upvoted my comment if I had commented my comment earlier than yours :)

Comment: @Amit Joki: Could have, but 15 seconds difference means I had already written it :P

Comment: @BayuSanjaya  I'll leave it for you to decide, but at the moment, I'd like to point `2 > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can also concatenate the text of all text boxes `id="nilai"` like this:

```
var total = "";
var l = parseInt($("#nilai").length);

for(var i=1;i<=l;i++){
    total += $("#nilai:nth-child('" + i + "')").val();
}
```

Comment: Running jQuery selectors over and over is very inefficient (especially complex selectors). Get the elements once and iterate over them.

Comment: Why running jQuery selectors over and over is very inefficient? in fact it worked also.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZeeshan because of reasons

Comment: It is pretty obvious you should not call a slow function n times when once will do. This is basic programming (and general advice for jQuery selectors).